# OAuthOptions.Scope Cannot Be Assigned To

Tags: oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-authentication

I'm trying to implement LinkedIn/OAuth authentication in my ASP.NET Core 2.0 app and I need to set the scope to `{ "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" }` so that I can user's email, profile image, etc.

When I try to set the scope in the following code, I'm getting the following error:

> Property or indexer 'OAuthOptions.Scope' cannot be assigned to -- it's
>   read-only.

Here's the code:

```
services.AddOAuth(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {

   options.SignInScheme = "LinkedIn";
   options.ClientId = "1234567890";
   options.ClientSecret = "1234567890";
   options.CallbackPath = "/linkedin-callback";

   // Configure the LinkedIn endpoints                
   options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization",
   options.TokenEndpoint = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken",
   options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))",

   options.Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" };

   options.Events = new OAuthEvents
   {
        OnCreatingTicket = OnCreatingTicketLinkedInCallBack,
        OnTicketReceived = OnTicketReceivedCallback
   };
})
```

Any idea how I can set the scope?

P.S. I tried to adapt the code from my ASP.NET Core 1.1. This code was working fine in the ASP.NET Core 1.1 app.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `Scope = { "r_basicprofile", "r_emailaddress" }` syntax is only available when using object initialization. Here, the `options` object is not instantiated from your code but directly provided by ASP.NET Core so you can't use this syntax.

The good news is that `Scope` property is a collection (internally, a hash set) so you can simply do:

```
options.Scope.Add("r_basicprofile");
options.Scope.Add("r_emailaddress");
```

If you want to get rid of the default scopes, you can remove them using `options.Scope.Remove("scope")` or `options.Scope.Clear()`.